# firebase realtime DB querying date between 2 dates does not match anything

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I am trying to find all the objects that are between two dates. the code look like below

```
getPendingOrders(dateFrom:number, dateTo:number){
    console.log('start of getPendingOrders with dateFrom:' + dateFrom + " dateTo:" + dateTo)
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
      {
       this.db.list('orders',
                     ref =>  ref.orderByChild("order/_date").startAt(dateFrom).endAt(dateTo)
       ).snapshotChanges().subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log('response:' + JSON.stringify(res))
          resolve(res)
        },
        err => {
          console.log(err)
          reject(err)
        }
      )
      })
  }
```

The console is printing:

```
start of getPendingOrders with dateFrom:1538265600000 dateTo:1538352000000
```

My data is like below in db

```
"-LNc1K09FDXGW7PrS9wu" : {
    "order" : {
      "_date" : "1538269987967",
      "_deliveryType" : "Delivery",
      "_estDeliveryTime" : "12:NaN AM",
      "_isPaid" : false,
      "_location" : "djdjdj",
      "_orderNumber" : "VikKumar-87967",
    }
  },
```

but my code does not return any data. Not sure why?  Just to add in this case if i remove .endAt then it works. so somehow upper bound does not work

Comment: Could you include your `ref` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that `dateFrom` and `dateTo` are numbers (See `(dateFrom:number, dateTo:number)`) and that you store `_date` as a string in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this line:

`ref =>  ref.orderByChild("order/_date").startAt(dateFrom).endAt(dateTo)`

to this:

`ref =>  ref.child("order").orderByChild("_date").startAt(dateFrom).endAt(dateTo)`

Comment: though i knew but still gave a try. no luck with that.