# firebase realtime DB: TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am having query like below

```
var db = admin.database();
    var ref = db.ref('orders') ref.orderByChild("order/_date").startAt(begDate).endAt(endDate).once("value").then(
        (resp) =>   { 
..
}).catch(
                (err) => console.log('failed in sales report:' + err)
        )
```

it throws below

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
```

The data looks like below

```
orders: {
  "-LNMPXMb1SGSnkDaEMQO" : {
    "order" : {
      "_cgst" : "11.90",
      "_date" : "1538368446413",
      "_location" : "kapashera",
      "_orderNumber" : "VikKumar-21247",
      "_orderStatus" : "Delivered",
    }
  },
```

At the time of execution the begDate and endDate are:

```
begDate:1538352000000 endDate:1538438400000
```

So two problems:
1.The error itself. How can I avoid throwing error if no match?
2. Why is the above record not matching when the date value is between begDate and endDate?

Comment: What is the type of begDate and endDate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably doing the same error than in you other question of yesterday: [firebase realtime DB querying date between 2 dates does not match anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52573975/firebase-realtime-db-querying-date-between-2-dates-does-not-match-anything)

Therefore, the reason is probably because `begDate` and `endDate` are numbers but you store `_date` as a string in your database.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `toISOString` when you save to fb

```
var _date = new Date().toISOString()
```

and

```
var d = new Date();
var year = d.getFullYear();
var month = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDate();

var begDate = new Date(year - 1, month, day).toISOString();
var endDate = new Date(year + 1, month, day).toISOString();
```